# Need to generate PWM for sine wave inverter without using microcontroller

Tags: inverter

I tried a lot but the output wave is coming as **pulsating square wave**.
And I didn't want to include microcontroller in my circuit.[image]

I am attaching my circuit for reference of inverter using IGBTs.
I have generated PWM using schmidtt trigger ic (74ac14) and a delay opamp circuit.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  have you generated a sinewave & a triangle wave & passed both into a comparator?

Comment: what do you mean by pulsating square wave?

Comment: For a H-bridge you need PWM and maybe some logic control for direction control. Easy to put together using simple logic circuits. to generate a PWM i would start of with 555 timer first maybe. I am not sure exactly what you are after though. How do you intend to control Pulse-width with this circuit? What is your reasoning?

Comment: Andy aka is correct. That circuit will not work. You are fortunate that you have not actually plugged it in. Start over and learn more about bridge design.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, and no, that H bridge will never work. If you have tried it you will find that on anything above a supply of a few tens of volts the lower IGBTs will now be dead.

Reason: to turn on the upper IGBTs you need to raise the gate voltage higher than the emitter and this means the gate voltage on the lower IGBTs will be a few hundred voltage above their emitter voltage (0 volts) and will be dead.

But wait, all is not lost, the Op-amp that drives the gates can never reach an output that is more than +15 volts and this saves the day. However, to make that H bridge work you need a drive level to the upper IGBTs that has a common mode voltage of the 300 volt supply rail.

Your circuit is [pants](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pants) and you need to really start from scratch and do some learning on H bridge drivers.

If you just want a logic level PWM signal that is modulated by an analogue signal then look to the [LTC6992](http://www.linear.com/docs/29337): -

[image]

Comment: The question still remains unanswered!! that how can we generate PWM for pure sine wave inverter without using  microcontroller

Comment: I've provided info in my answer about the LTC6992 analogue to PWM chip. Very nice it is as well.